# LINQ and XmlNodes elements

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, linq-to-xml

I am trying to return the the attribute values from this XML, which is a collection of XmlNodes called from a Sharepoint Webmethod.

**XML Data**

```
 <Lists xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">

    <List DocTemplateUrl="" DefaultViewUrl="/Lists/Announcements/AllItems.aspx" MobileDefaultViewUrl="" ID="{E6172717-EB95-4845-B8CB-8161832565C6}" Title="Announcements" Description="Use the Announcements list to post messages on the home page of your site." ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itann.gif" Name="{E6172717-EB95-4845-B8CB-8161832565C6}" BaseType="0" FeatureId="00bfea71-d1ce-42de-9c63-a44004ce0104" />


    <List DocTemplateUrl="" DefaultViewUrl="/Lists/Calendar/calendar.aspx" MobileDefaultViewUrl="" ID="{C0735477-BE48-4DDF-9D93-3E1F8E993CEC}" Title="Calendar" Description="Use the Calendar list to keep informed of upcoming meetings, deadlines, and other important events." ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itevent.gif" Name="{C0735477-BE48-4DDF-9D93-3E1F8E993CEC}" BaseType="0" FeatureId="00bfea71-ec85-4903-972d-ebe475780106" />

///... Several more like this
    </Lists>
```

I have been following a few different guides, just been going through [like this one on DiC](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/218979-linq-to-xml/), and I've managed to get the examples to work.

```
 public List<Dictionary<string, XmlAttribute>> GetListData(XmlNode collection)
    {            
        #region Test
    string nodeInput = Convert.ToString(collection.OuterXml);

    TextReader sr = new StringReader(nodeInput);

                 //from <List> node, decendant of <Lists>
    var lists = (from list in XElement.Load(sr).Descendants("List")
                 //where the baseType element value equals 0
                 where int.Parse(list.Element("BaseType").Value) == 0
                 //Output the titles values to a list
                 select list.Element("Title").Value).ToList();
     }

    #endregion
```

I've been trying to adapt a few of the examples to my data to get more of an idea how it works, but this query has not returned any results unlike I expected. I've written besides each line in a comment what I thought the command was doing, could someone illuminate my mistake?

---

**Solution**

Very easy to find once I knew namespace was the issue.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669152.aspx
C# unlike VB requires the namespace even when the nodes aren't prefixed by it.

So I needed an `XNamespace`

```
    XNamespace nameSpace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/";
    XElement node = XElement.Parse(nodeInput);

    var lists = from list in node.Descendants(nameSpace + "List")
                select list;
    foreach (var list in lists)
    {
        var doc = list.Document;
    }
```

Comment: Your XML shows a namespace, but you're never using one. I'd expect you to not find any `List` elements with your current code...

Comment: Thanks, having a read up on xml namespaces now.

Comment: Amicable, a cleaner way to parse an `XmlNode` by `XElement` or `XDocument` is to use an `XmlNodeReader` over the `XmlNode` e.g. `XElement node; using (XmlReader xr = new XmlNodeReader(collection)) { node = XElement.Load(xr); } ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Very easy to find once I knew namespace was the issue.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669152.aspx
C# unlike VB requires the namespace even when the nodes aren't prefixed by it.

So I needed an `XNamespace`

```
    XNamespace nameSpace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/";
    XElement node = XElement.Parse(nodeInput);

    var lists = from list in node.Descendants(nameSpace + "List")
                select list;
    foreach (var list in lists)
    {
        var doc = list.Document;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/";

var lists = (from list in XElement.Parse(nodeInput).Descendants(ns + "List")
             where (int)list.Attribute(ns + "BaseType") == 0
             select (string)list.Attribute(ns + "Title")).ToList();
```